# What do you call the inability to see alternative solutions to a problem?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, conditioning

Once I "learned" for a condition in which you have a specific solution of a problem, but you are only thinking of it and do not realize there are other / probably more appropriate / solutions. Something like.. being stuck to an attempt of a solution.

---

So there was a name for it. But google results for tokens such as "Problem Solving Disease" lead me to nothing related.

Comment: One technical term is cognitive rigidity, and CRT (Cognitive remediation therapy) works to increase flexibility

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called the [Einstellung effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstellung_effect):

> ...Einstellung refers to a person's predisposition to solve a given problem in a specific manner even though "better" or more appropriate methods of solving the problem exist

It is related to the idea of [functional fixedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_fixedness):

> Functional fixedness is a cognitive bias that limits a person to using an object only in the way it is traditionally used. `